# Using variables with the same element id name when selecting them

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

This does not work on IE8, but in all other browsers:

```
myDialog = $('#myDialog');
somethingHere = $('#somethingHere');
```

In other words, if the variable name and the element id name are the SAME jQuery 1.5.1 dies on IE8.

As long as they are different it works.

```
myDialog1 = $('myDialog');
```

Took me just 3 hours to realize that. :-|

Is that a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: Submit it as a bug report.... http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket

Comment: This is the wrong place to report jQuery bugs. Try jquery.com instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably has to do with the fact that if you declare a global variable with the same name as a DOM element ID, it will conflict in the global namespace. I think this will cause you problems in any browser, maybe IE just complains more. e.g. in a script debugger in any browser:

```
<div id="myDialog">

> window.myDialog

.. <div id="myDialog">

> myDialog = "hello";

.. "hello"

>  window.myDialog

.. "hello"
```

Whoops! No longer possible to reference the DOM element by ID. DOM element IDs and global variable share the same namespace.

Comment: Ok. This worked fine on all browsers but IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Try prefacing variable declarations with `var`: `var myDialog = $('#myDialog');`